I am working on deeplink for flutter application.It is perfectly working with the debug mode.but it is not working in release build
I am working with deep links in flutter app.I had configured and it is perfectly working with the debug mode. But when i tried to work on release build it is not working and just opening the website.
I want the solution to make this working on release build of my flutter app.
I had added intent-filter in android manifest file.
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="applink-steama.web.app"
                    android:pathPrefix="/app"
                />
            </intent-filter>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To fix this issue and to open the app with URL in release or production mode. In android, we need to upload it to the play console.
After Uploading and setting up things in the play console.
In the left side menu bar:
Goto Setup -> App Signing.
Under the App signing key certificate tag. You will find the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint.
Add this fingerprint in the assetlinks.json file :
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": <your_package_name>,
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        <sha256_cert_generated_from_your_machine>,
        <sha_256_cert_taken_from_play_console>
      ]
    }
  }
]

Again deploy the file in your domain. Now it will be working both in debug and release mode.
